# How do i find the path of a linux program?

Tags: linux, shell

i need to find the complete path of a given Linux executeable?
How can i do this?

For example the real path of cat is /bin/cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the which command:

```
$ which ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `which` or `locate`:

```
$ which cat
/bin/cat
```

Answer (score 1):

`which program` or `whereis program`

```
$  whatis which
which                (1)  - shows the full path of (shell) commands

$  whatis whereis
whereis              (1)  - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```